# Segmentation Fault when calling bpy.ops.render.render (script using Blender as a Python Module on Mac)

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I am using Blender as Python Module on Mac and now attempting to create a scene programmatically and take a screenshot of what the camera sees but I am getting a "Segmentation Fault: 11" when running the following script (on calling bpy.ops.render.render).

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import bmesh

scene = bpy.context.scene

# Create the cube
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('cube')
ob = bpy.data.objects.new('cube', mesh)
scene.collection.objects.link(ob)
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=1.0)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()

# Create a light
light_data = bpy.data.lights.new('light', type='POINT')
light = bpy.data.objects.new('light', light_data)
scene.collection.objects.link(light)
light.location = mathutils.Vector((3, -4.2, 5))

# Create the camera
cam_data = bpy.data.cameras.new('camera')
cam = bpy.data.objects.new('camera', cam_data)
scene.collection.objects.link(cam)
scene.camera = cam

cam.location = mathutils.Vector((6, -3, 5))
cam.rotation_euler = mathutils.Euler((0.9, 0.0, 1.1))

# Render settings
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'

filepath = "/tmp/image_blender.png"

# Segmentation fault caused by this line
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = 1)

img = bpy.data.images['Render Result']
img.save_render(filepath, scene=scene)
```

I'd love to get some help and understand if there's an issue with the script or with the way I installed/configured Blender as a python module. Thanks in advance!

P.S.: [Copy/Paste of Problem Detail and System Configuration](https://pastebin.com/Gc1ndGwZ)

Comment: I can't reproduce a crash. It could be that something went wrong when building Blender as python module. Without a stack trace it's hard to tell what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Ditto. Can confirm no hassle either. Albeit I'm on Ubuntu, python 3.7.5, version 2.8.2 built  from master.  Is it Ok running in blender background mode?

Comment: Thanks @RobertGützkow! I have added a link to what was generated by the mac. Not sure if it's useful.

Comment: @batFINGER: can you clarify what you mean by running in bender background mode?

Comment: `blender -b` from the command prompt. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/index.html#command-line

Comment: I can reproduce this, having the same error. MacOS 10.15. Using bpy python module.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same error with the bpy module on MacOS 10.15, python 3.7.7 and blender 2.83/2.82

I was able to fix it by changing to a different renderer.

you can add this line: `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'`

before: `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = 1)`

And it will no longer seg fault